# SqlCommand C#, составление сложного запроса

Tags: c#, sql

Есть три таблицы, Первая Departament(поля: Id, Name), Вторая Workers(Id, Departament_id, WorkerInfo_id) Третья WorkerInfo(Id, SecondName, FirstName, Position). Мне нужно запросом стянуть Departament.Id, Departament.Name, Workers.Id, WorkerInfo.SecondName, WorkerInfo.FirstName, WorkerInfo.Position
Вот что я пытался написать

```
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Departament.Id, Departament.Name, WorkerInfo.SecondName," +
                    "WorkerInfo.FirstName, WorkerInfo.Position, Workers.Id FROM [Workers] " +
                    "LEFT JOIN [Workers] ON Departament.Id = @id" +
                    "LEFT JOIN [WorkerInfo] ON Workers.WorkerInfo_id = WorkerInfo.Id", SqlConnection);
```

Comment: Вы сперва напишите запрос - чисто SQL, и только когда он заработает - пихайте его в шарпея.

Comment: Не хватает пробела между `@id` и `LEFT`. **Всегда** выводите на печать готовый текст запроса для проверки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Не хватает пробела между @id и LEFT. Всегда выводите на печать готовый текст запроса для проверки. – Alexander Petrov

Вопрос решён